# I can't use Qt on my windows

Tags: qt, windows-8, qt-creator

I have just installed Qt 5.0.1 on Windows 8, but when I opened Qt Creator and made a new Qt GUI Application named `test_1` and then run the project it said `:-1: error: error: ..test_1test_1main.cpp: No such file or directory` and `:-1: error: fatal error: no input files`.

```
#------------------------------------------------- #
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-03-13T16:17:47 # 
#-------------------------------------------------
QT += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h
FORMS += mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: Show us your `.pro` file.  The big hint is: `:-1: error: fatal error: no input files`.

Comment: QT installation path cannot have space.

Comment: e this is my .pro  and my installation path is Qt, there is no space,thank you!

Comment: i find that it always get 'test_1main.cpp' but not 'maim.cpp'  and if i replace my 'main.cpp' with 'test_1main.cpp',then it will try find 'test_1test_1main.cpp'

Comment: Would I be right in assuming `test_1test_1main.cpp` does not exist, but `test_1\test_1\main.cpp` does?

Comment: yes it should be test_1\main.cpp

Comment: Do pro files require you to escape the backslash ? Try replacing that with / instead for paths.

Comment: It looks like they do: http://tamss60.tamoggemon.com/2010/09/28/change-to-pro-file-syntax-unescaped-backslashes-are-deprecated/